# Split text using regex (Java / Kotlin) with multiple delimiter

Tags: java, regex, string, kotlin

I have a string row with **code** (2 chars) and **name** separated by **>**.

eg. `CP >RENATO DE SA`, `CP >FRAIS`. I want to split this row in pairs with **code** and **name**.

**I have this text:**

```
CT >RUSSO CT >JOSE AQUINO CP >RENATO DE SA CP >FRAIS CF >TAMARA STUCCHI CF >VANESSA JULKOWS CM >CRISTINA LOUSTA CM >HANS KROESCHEL CM >CONCEICAO MACIE CM >AIMEE FRARI CM >JONNY MOREIRA
```

**Desired result:**

```
CT, RUSSO 
CT, JOSE AQUINO 
CP, RENATO DE SA 
CP, FRAIS 
CF, TAMARA STUCCHI 
CF, VANESSA JULKOWS 
CM, CRISTINA LOUSTA 
CM, HANS KROESCHEL 
CM, CONCEICAO MACIE 
CM, AIMEE FRARI 
CM, JONNY MOREIRA
```

Comment: Are the pairs always separated by exactly one space?  Can you just `s.split( " " );` (OK, nm, I see why that wouldn't work.)

Comment: They are separated by ` >`

Comment: I think negative lookahead might split off the pairs for you: `s.split( " (?!>)" );`  Untested though.

Comment: @markspace it didn't work, I'm almost target with `((\w{2}).\>((\w|\s)+)(?!\s\w{2}.\>)?)`, but it's including *code* from next group. eg. `CT, JOSE AQUINO CP`

Comment: are the code is always two upper letters?

Comment: @YCF_L yes, only uppers

Comment: Try to use `replace` like this `s.replace(Regex("(\\w{2}) >"),"\n$1, ")`

Comment: Try `(C[A-Z])\s+(>)(.*?(?=\sC[A-Z]\s|$))` [here](https://regex101.com/r/ythLvA/1/) and replace with `\1, \3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split with this regex `( (?=[A-Z]{2} >)| >)`

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val input = "CT >RUSSO CT >JOSE AQUINO CP >RENATO DE SA CP >FRAIS ...";
    val split = input.split("( (?=[A-Z]{2} >)| >)".toRegex())
    for (i in split.indices step 2) 
       println(split[i] + ", " + split[i + 1])
}
```

Outputs

```
CT, RUSSO
CT, JOSE AQUINO
CP, RENATO DE SA
CP, FRAIS
CF, TAMARA STUCCHI
CF, VANESSA JULKOWS
CM, CRISTINA LOUSTA
CM, HANS KROESCHEL
CM, CONCEICAO MACIE
CM, AIMEE FRARI
CM, JONNY MOREIRA
```

You can check the [**ideone demo**](https://ideone.com/uvR66k)

## regex detail :

The regex will match two things `( (?=[A-Z]{2} >)| >)`

- `(?=[A-Z]{2} >` space followed by two upper letters then a space then a `>` sign, but we need the two Upper letters for that we use `?=` a positive lookahead
- `|` or
- `>` a space followed by `>` sign

You can check the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/g4U9Tj/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can do without regex:

`replace(" >", ", ").replace(" ","\\n");`

or (using regex)

`replaceAll("\\s>", ", ").replaceAll("\\s","\\n");`

Answer (score 0):

string.split("[÷+[-]]".toRegex())
look here i needed to split string with + ,div , -
you just need to convert the string to regex
As - is special symbol in regex we need to wrap it

hope in the same way you will be able to solve your problem too